# Nested drag and drop using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

To Drop items into dropped items

```
<table id='list1' >
</table>

<ul id="list2" >
</ul>

<table id='list3' >
<tr><td>test<ul style="min-height: 100px;border:1px solid red" class="drop-container"></ul></td></tr>
</table>
```

I have following code

```
$( "#list3 li" ).draggable({
            connectToSortable: "#list2",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
});
$( "#list1 li" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#list2",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        greedy: true
});
```

How  can i drop list1 item into list2 directly and list2's `ul` Layout tag  which will come from list3 by drag and drop API of jquery?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/nkvzdwk9/1/

Comment: You want to sort items and drag/drop between lists? Or other?

Comment: I want to drag and drop items between lists means first i drop item to list2 from taking list3 and then i will drop into the inner area of dropped item from taking list1

Comment: First drag layout1 and in that want to drag media

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what you want to achieve can be summarized like this

> Step 1 : Drag and drop some Layout(which is inside `li` tag) from `#list3` to `#list2`.
>
> Step 2 : Drag and drop some media(which is also inside `li` tag) from
>   `#list1` to `#list2` directly and also `#list2` Layout's ul tag `.drop-container` which is now has been dragged to `#list2` .

Currently , you are dropping `#list1 li` into `#list 2` , but it should be dropped into `.drop-container of #list2` or `#list2`(if you want to add `#list li` to `#list2` directly)

so `#list1 li` should be connected to `.drop-container of #list2` and `#list2`

```
$("#list1 li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#list2 .drop-container,#list2",//both element should be connected
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    greedy: true
});
```

After that, the `sortable` API needs to be added to `.drop-container of #list2` only after `#list2` has received some Layout from `#list3` of

So call `sortable` on `#list2 .drop-container` inside receive method of `sortable` of `list2`.
Now your receive function of `#list2` becomes

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui);
        console.log(event);
        var this_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
        var preview = $(itemContext).html().replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');

        $(itemContext).attr("id", this_id);
        $(itemContext).css("width", $('#list2').width() - 20).addClass("ui-state-default").height('auto');
        $(itemContext).html(preview);

 //Modified code starts here, the sortable should be added here

        $("#list2 .drop-container").sortable({//call sortable to every element which you want to drop to.
            connectWith: "#list1",
            over: function () {
                removeIntent = false;
            },
            out: function () {
                removeIntent = true;
            },
            beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
                itemContext = ui.item.context;
                if (removeIntent == true) {
                    ui.item.remove();
                    disp($("#list2").sortable('toArray'));
                }
                //console.log(itemContext);

            },
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui);
                console.log(event);
                var this_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
                var preview = $(itemContext).html().replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');

                $(itemContext).attr("id", this_id);
                $(itemContext).css("width", $('#list2').width() - 20).addClass("ui-state-default").height('auto');
                $(itemContext).html(preview);

                //console.log(this_id);
                //console.log(preview);

            }
        }); //.disableSelection()

    //end of modified code

        //console.log(this_id);
        //console.log(preview);

    }
});
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ankit2038/nkvzdwk9/7/show/), [full code](http://jsfiddle.net/ankit2038/nkvzdwk9/7/)

Comment: Thanks fot reply. But it is not dropping to the particular layout's ul tag

Comment: Edited see the changes , now it will drop inside ul `.drop-container`

Comment: but it it not allow to drop to list2 directly means can drop is layout or directly in list2 and also it is not allowing to drop already dropped media

Comment: It is not working properly if first i drop direct media item and next i drop layout and if then i try to drop into layout it is not working.

Comment: I accidently called sortable again on `list2`. Fixed now, thanks